# Vuejs Ajax call and dataTable

Tags: datatables, vuejs2

I'm using Vuejs and dataTable for one of my project. I make an Ajax call and push data into an array. After that I use v-for to loop the data in the `<tr>` tag. Most of the time it doesn't work. The table loads as soon as the page has finished loading.. it takes a bit of time to receive the ajax data. Here is the output. It says no data available in the table [image]

So the serch option doesn't work properly. I thought to use a setTimeout function (which was a bad idea) to load the table after a bit of time. What would be the proper way to do it? Sharing the code :

```
    new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                data: {
                    entries: [],
                },
                methods:{
                    getData(){
                        var route = '/admin/temporary-enrolled-students';
                        this.$http.get(route).then((response)=>{
                            for(var i = 0; i< response.data.length;i++)
                            {
                                this.entries.push({
                                    scId: response.data[i].id,
                                    name: response.data[i].user.name,
                                    phone: response.data[i].user.phone,
                                    email: response.data[i].user.email,
                                    courseId: response.data[i].course.id,
                                    courseName: response.data[i].course.course_title,
                                    expiryDate: response.data[i].expiry_date,
                                    shares: response.data[i].number_of_shares,
                                    expired: (response.data[i].expired == 1),
                                    enrollDate: response.data[i].created_at
                                })
                            }

                        })
                    },
                },
                mounted(){
                    this.getData();
                },
            });
//data table
$(function () {
            setTimeout(()=> {          
                $("#temp-enroll").DataTable({
                    "paging": true,
                    "ordering": false,
                    "info": true,
                    "autoWidth": false
                });
            },1000);
        });
```

in blade:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I tried this and working exactly what I have wanted. Thanks everyone for supporting.

```
new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                data: {
                    entries: [],
                },
                methods:{
                    getData(){
                        var route = '/admin/temporary-enrolled-students';
                        this.$http.get(route).then((response)=>{
                            for(var i = 0; i< response.data.length;i++)
                            {
                                this.entries.push({
                                    scId: response.data[i].id,
                                    name: response.data[i].user.name,
                                    ............................
                                    ......................
                                    enrollDate: response.data[i].created_at
                                })
                            }

                        }).then(()=>{
                          $("#temp-enroll").DataTable({
                            "paging": true,
                            "ordering": false,
                            "info": true,
                            "autoWidth": false
                             });
                          });
                    },
                },
                mounted(){
                    this.getData();
                },
            });
```

Comment: Note for someone who is wondering how did `$http` come in place! Use `vue-resource` and you can refer guide here: https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource

Comment: I´m having i think a similar problem, but in my case i have the ajax POST call with server-side:true inside the table. That url will return not only the data but also the buttons in each row(like edit or delete) and inside this buttons i have for example @click="editRow" and vue is not rendering this because it comes later, how would i resolve this? can you help me?

Comment: I would suggest you to avoid jquery at all. Vue and jquery does not play nice together.. and using them together will be a very bad practice. If you are using vue, then only stick to vue. Its very powerful and able to do anything much more efficiently than jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You could try watch property https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers. From the doc:

> While computed properties are more appropriate in most cases, there
> are times when a custom watcher is necessary. That’s why Vue provides
> a more generic way to react to data changes through the watch option.
> This is most useful when you want to perform asynchronous or expensive
> operations in response to changing data.

Answer (score 0):

I think someone mentioned that a computed property is the way to go, and that is what I would recommend as well.

The reason why is that as soon as your template makes a reference to the computed property, this triggers your ajax call.  The page will then render any other available elements, and when your ajax call returns, it will then render the data it received.  No special action in code is required.

Anyway, here is what it would look like...

In your html, as an example...

```
 <table>
        <tr v-for="item in serverData">
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.someOtherValue}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

export default {
  name: 'pets',
  data () {
    return {
    }
  },
  computed: {
    serverData: function() {
      // ajax call using axios - returns a json array []
      axios.get("http://localhost:8080/getSomeData")
      .success(function(data) {
          return data;
      };
    }
}
```

}

Notice the return in the success promise returned from the ajax call - there is no need to store the data to another variable (and you should definitely not have to loop through it like the noob coder example above shows.  Do that on the server, return an array ready to render - if it isn't your web service, then write your own that calls the original and do the data manipulation there).

The parts of your template that reference the computed value will render after the data arrives - there is no need to watch it.

Hope this helps!

Vue is the bomb!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <template>
    <div class="panel panel-default tablecontainer">
        <div class="panel-heading">ChartBookin Import</div>
        <br>
        <div class='col-md-12'>
            <div class='col-md-3'></div>
            <div class='col-md-3'>
                <div class="panel panel-default">

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <commitChart :width="150"
                                     :height="150"></commitChart>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class='col-md-3'>
                <div class="panel panel-default">

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <InboxMessage :width="150"
                                     :height="150"></InboxMessage>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class='col-md-3'>
                <label> by Account </label>
                <select v-model="teamId" class="form-control" rows="3">
                    <option VALUE="" disabled> CHOISIR UN TEAM</option>
                    <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id">{{option.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-3'>
                <label> by Date</label>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="daterange"
                           value="01/01/2017-01/31/2017"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-5'></div>
            <div class='col-md-1'>
                <label>Records</label>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <select v-model="elementsPerPage" class="form-control">

                        <option v-for="option in filtre" v-bind:value="option">
                            {{ option }}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="sixthTable">

                <table class="table-bordered table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th v-for=" (key,value) in rows[0]" v-on:click="sortTable(value)">{{value}}
                            <div class="arrow" v-if="value == sortColumn"
                                 v-bind:class="[ascending ? 'arrow_up' : 'arrow_down']"></div>
                        </th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    <tr v-if=" rows.length > 0" v-for="row in rows">
                        <td v-for="(key, value) in row">{{ key }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a :href="'/stat_booking_import/' + row.Id">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
                            </a>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr v-else> No Result Founded</tr>
                    </tbody>

                </table>
                <div class="pagination">


                    <div id="paginatebutton">
                        <a href="#">&laquo;</a>
                        <a class="" v-for="i in num_pages()"
                           v-bind:class="[i == currentPage ? 'active' : '']"
                           v-on:click="change_page(i)">{{i}}
                        </a>
                        <a href="#">&raquo;</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12" id="paginatetexte">
                        <p v-if="pages > (elementsPerPage*currentPage) ">
                            Showing 1 to {{elementsPerPage * currentPage }} of {{ pages }} records
                        </p>
                        <p v-else>
                            Showing 1 to {{pages}} of {{ pages }} records
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>


</template>


<script>
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import CommitChart from './Mail';
    import InboxMessage from './Inbox';


    export default {
        components: {
            CommitChart,
            InboxMessage

        },
        data() {
            return {
                filtre: [10, 25, 50, 100],
                option: 0,
                options: [],
                currentPage: 1,
                elementsPerPage: 10,
                pages: 0,
                ascending: false,
                sortColumn: '',
                startdate: null,
                enddate: null,
                options: [],
                teamId: null,
                columns: [],
                messages: [],
                date: 0,
                rows: {},
            }
        },

        created() {
            this.getData();
            this.getTeams();
            this.getMailInbox();

        },
        mounted() {
            let vm = this;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
                    ranges: {
                        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')]
                    },
                    locale: {
                        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
                    },
                });

                $('.applyBtn').click(function () {
                    vm.startdate = $("input[name=daterangepicker_start]").val();
                    vm.enddate = $("input[name=daterangepicker_end]").val();
                    vm.getData();


                });
                $('input[name="daterange"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
                    vm.startdate = $("input[name=daterangepicker_start]").val();
                    vm.enddate = $("input[name=daterangepicker_end]").val();
                    vm.getData();
                });

            });
        },
        watch: {
            date: function () {
                this.getData();
            },
            teamId: function () {
                this.getData();
            },
            elementsPerPage: function () {
                this.getData();
            }


        },
        methods: {

            getData() {

                axios.get(`/admin/stat_booking_import.json/` + this.startdate + `/` + this.teamId + `/` + this.enddate + `/` + this.elementsPerPage + `?page=` + this.currentPage)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.rows = response.data.elements.data;
                        this.columns = Object.keys(this.rows[0]);
                        this.pages = response.data.elements.total_element;
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        this.errors.push(e)
                    })

            },
            getTeams() {
                axios.get('/admin/team.json')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.options = response.data.data;
                        this.errors = [];

                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        e.message = "aucun resultat trouvé essayer de choisir une autre date";
                        this.errors.push(e)
                    })
            },
            getMailInbox() {
                axios.get(`/mailstorage.json`)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.messages = response.data.data;
                        console.log(this.messages);

                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        this.errors.push(e)
                    });
            },

            sortTable(col) {
                if (this.sortColumn === col) {
                    this.ascending = !this.ascending;
                } else {
                    this.ascending = true;
                    this.sortColumn = col;
                }

                var ascending = this.ascending;

                this.rows.sort(function (a, b) {
                    if (a[col] > b[col]) {
                        return ascending ? 1 : -1
                    } else if (a[col] < b[col]) {
                        return ascending ? -1 : 1
                    }
                    return 0;
                })
            },
            num_pages() {

                return Math.ceil(this.pages / this.elementsPerPage);
            },
            get_rows() {
                var start = (this.currentPage - 1) * this.elementsPerPage;
                var end = start + this.elementsPerPage;
                return this.rows.slice(start, end);
            },
            change_page(page) {
                this.currentPage = page;
                this.getData();
            }
        },

    }


</script>
<style type="text/css">
    table {
        width: 100%;
    }

    table td {
        text-align: center;
    }

    table td {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 8px;

    }

    table td:last-child {
        border-right: none;
    }

    .pagination {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .pagination a {
        color: #3097D1;
        float: left;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: background-color .3s;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    .pagination a.active {
        background-color: #3097D1;
        color: white;
        border: 1px solid #3097D1;
    }

    .arrow_down {
        background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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')
    }

    .arrow_up {
        background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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')
    }

    .arrow {
        float: right;
        width: 12px;
        height: 15px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        background-position-y: bottom;
    }

    .number {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 4px 10px;
        margin: 0px 5px;
        cursor: pointer;

    }

    .number:hover,
    .number.active {
        background-color: #3097D1;
        border-color: #3097D1;
    }

    #paginatetexte {
        padding-top: 6%;
```

```js
import Vue from 'vue'


new Vue({
    el: '#statistique',
    render: h => h(require('./StatBookingImport.vue'))
});
```

```css
<style type="text/css">
    table {
        width: 100%;
    }

    table td {
        text-align: center;
    }

    table td {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 8px;

    }

    table td:last-child {
        border-right: none;
    }

    .pagination {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .pagination a {
        color: #3097D1;
        float: left;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        transition: background-color .3s;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    .pagination a.active {
        background-color: #3097D1;
        color: white;
        border: 1px solid #3097D1;
    }

    .arrow_down {
        background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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')
    }

    .arrow_up {
        background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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')
    }

    .arrow {
        float: right;
        width: 12px;
        height: 15px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        background-position-y: bottom;
    }

    .number {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 4px 10px;
        margin: 0px 5px;
        cursor: pointer;

    }

    .number:hover,
    .number.active {
        background-color: #3097D1;
        border-color: #3097D1;
    }

    #paginatetexte {
        padding-top: 6%;
    }

    #paginatebutton {
        border-radius: 1px;
    }

    .tablecontainer {

        margin-right: 2%;
        margin-left: 2%;
    }

    .mailinbox {
        margin-left: 1%;
    }

</style>
```

```html
<template>
    <div class="panel panel-default tablecontainer">
        <div class="panel-heading">ChartBookin Import</div>
        <br>
        <div class='col-md-12'>
            <div class='col-md-3'></div>
            <div class='col-md-3'>
                <div class="panel panel-default">

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <commitChart :width="150"
                                     :height="150"></commitChart>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class='col-md-3'>
                <div class="panel panel-default">

                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <InboxMessage :width="150"
                                     :height="150"></InboxMessage>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class='col-md-3'>
                <label> by Account </label>
                <select v-model="teamId" class="form-control" rows="3">
                    <option VALUE="" disabled> CHOISIR UN TEAM</option>
                    <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.id">{{option.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-3'>
                <label> by Date</label>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="daterange"
                           value="01/01/2017-01/31/2017"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='col-md-5'></div>
            <div class='col-md-1'>
                <label>Records</label>
                <div class="form-group">

                    <select v-model="elementsPerPage" class="form-control">

                        <option v-for="option in filtre" v-bind:value="option">
                            {{ option }}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="sixthTable">

                <table class="table-bordered table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th v-for=" (key,value) in rows[0]" v-on:click="sortTable(value)">{{value}}
                            <div class="arrow" v-if="value == sortColumn"
                                 v-bind:class="[ascending ? 'arrow_up' : 'arrow_down']"></div>
                        </th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    <tr v-if=" rows.length > 0" v-for="row in rows">
                        <td v-for="(key, value) in row">{{ key }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a :href="'/stat_booking_import/' + row.Id">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>
                            </a>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr v-else> No Result Founded</tr>
                    </tbody>

                </table>
                <div class="pagination">


                    <div id="paginatebutton">
                        <a href="#">&laquo;</a>
                        <a class="" v-for="i in num_pages()"
                           v-bind:class="[i == currentPage ? 'active' : '']"
                           v-on:click="change_page(i)">{{i}}
                        </a>
                        <a href="#">&raquo;</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12" id="paginatetexte">
                        <p v-if="pages > (elementsPerPage*currentPage) ">
                            Showing 1 to {{elementsPerPage * currentPage }} of {{ pages }} records
                        </p>
                        <p v-else>
                            Showing 1 to {{pages}} of {{ pages }} records
                        </p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>


</template>


<script>
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import CommitChart from './Mail';
    import InboxMessage from './Inbox';


    export default {
        components: {
            CommitChart,
            InboxMessage

        },
        data() {
            return {
                filtre: [10, 25, 50, 100],
                option: 0,
                options: [],
                currentPage: 1,
                elementsPerPage: 10,
                pages: 0,
                ascending: false,
                sortColumn: '',
                startdate: null,
                enddate: null,
                options: [],
                teamId: null,
                columns: [],
                messages: [],
                date: 0,
                rows: {},
            }
        },

        created() {
            this.getData();
            this.getTeams();
            this.getMailInbox();

        },
        mounted() {
            let vm = this;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
                    ranges: {
                        'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                        'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                        'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                        'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')]
                    },
                    locale: {
                        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
                    },
                });

                $('.applyBtn').click(function () {
                    vm.startdate = $("input[name=daterangepicker_start]").val();
                    vm.enddate = $("input[name=daterangepicker_end]").val();
                    vm.getData();


                });
                $('input[name="daterange"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
                    vm.startdate = $("input[name=daterangepicker_start]").val();
                    vm.enddate = $("input[name=daterangepicker_end]").val();
                    vm.getData();
                });

            });
        },
        watch: {
            date: function () {
                this.getData();
            },
            teamId: function () {
                this.getData();
            },
            elementsPerPage: function () {
                this.getData();
            }


        },
        methods: {

            getData() {

                axios.get(`/admin/stat_booking_import.json/` + this.startdate + `/` + this.teamId + `/` + this.enddate + `/` + this.elementsPerPage + `?page=` + this.currentPage)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.rows = response.data.elements.data;
                        this.columns = Object.keys(this.rows[0]);
                        this.pages = response.data.elements.total_element;
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        this.errors.push(e)
                    })

            },
            getTeams() {
                axios.get('/admin/team.json')
                    .then(response => {
                        this.options = response.data.data;
                        this.errors = [];

                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        e.message = "aucun resultat trouvé essayer de choisir une autre date";
                        this.errors.push(e)
                    })
            },
            getMailInbox() {
                axios.get(`/mailstorage.json`)
                    .then(response => {
                        this.messages = response.data.data;
                        console.log(this.messages);

                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        this.errors.push(e)
                    });
            },

            sortTable(col) {
                if (this.sortColumn === col) {
                    this.ascending = !this.ascending;
                } else {
                    this.ascending = true;
                    this.sortColumn = col;
                }

                var ascending = this.ascending;

                this.rows.sort(function (a, b) {
                    if (a[col] > b[col]) {
                        return ascending ? 1 : -1
                    } else if (a[col] < b[col]) {
                        return ascending ? -1 : 1
                    }
                    return 0;
                })
            },
            num_pages() {

                return Math.ceil(this.pages / this.elementsPerPage);
            },
            get_rows() {
                var start = (this.currentPage - 1) * this.elementsPerPage;
                var end = start + this.elementsPerPage;
                return this.rows.slice(start, end);
            },
            change_page(page) {
                this.currentPage = page;
                this.getData();
            }
        },

    }


</script>
```

```
    }

    #paginatebutton {
        border-radius: 1px;
    }

    .tablecontainer {

        margin-right: 2%;
        margin-left: 2%;
    }

    .mailinbox {
        margin-left: 1%;
    }

</style>
```