# (datatable)vuejs data is updated and the length is changed to 1, but it is still displayed as html as the previous value

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, datatable

I referred to this link. It's the same way as mine.
[Vuejs Ajax call and dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176857/vuejs-ajax-call-and-datatable)

(I'm using Vuejs and dataTable for one of my project. I make an Ajax call and push data into an array. After that I use v-for to loop the data in the  tag.)

After creating Datatable, the table is displayed normally.
The problem is that v-for does not run normally when the list value in the data of vuejs changes.
**The data expressed in v-for does not normally apply to html even if the statusList[] value changes!**

[image: The statusList[] of the vuejs data is updated and the length is changed to 1, but it is still displayed as html as the previous value.]
[image: statusList data]

js)

```
var tbapplyListApp = new Vue({
el: "#tbapplyList",
data: {
    statusList: []
},
methods: {
    getComregstList: function() {
        var $this = this;
        AjaxUtil.post({
            url: GblVar.apiUrl + "/api/admin/regst/getRegstList",
            param: {
                ...
            },
            reqType: "json",
            success: function(res) {
                console.log("----getComregstList");
                $this.statusList = res.data;
            },
            finally: function(){
                console.log("-----statusList changed!");
                console.log($this.statusList);
                $('#tbapplyListTable').DataTable().destroy();
                $('#tbapplyListTable').DataTable( {
                    dom: 'Bfrtipl',
                    buttons: [
                        {
                            extend: 'excel',
                            text: 'DOWNLOAD'
                        }
                    ]
                });
            }
        });
    },
},
mounted: function() {
    this.getComregstList();
},
});
```

html)

```
<table id="tbapplyListTable" class="display">
                <colgroup>
                    <col width="16%"/>
                    <col width="17%"/>
                    <col width="17%"/>
                    <col width="17%"/>
                    <col width="17%"/>
                    <col width="16%"/>
                </colgroup>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>no</th>
                        <th>regstName</th>
                        <th>regstDt</th>
                        <th>regstStepName</th>
                        <th>mngName</th>
                        <th>confmTagStr</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="(status, index) in statusList" v-key="status.regstSeq" class="status_list">
                        <td v-text="statusList.length-index"></td>
                        <td v-text="status.regstName"></td>
                        <td v-text="status.regstDt"></td>
                        <td v-text="status.regstStepName"></td>
                        <td v-text="status.mngName"></td>
                        <td v-text="status.confmTagStr"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

And AjaxUtil.post appears to be clear. (I'm calling the API normally and I'm importing data normally)
It would be great if I could get some help!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the location and solved it.

```
success: function(res) {
    $('#tbapplyListTable').DataTable().destroy();
    $this.statusList = res.data;
},
finally: function(){
    $('#tbapplyListTable').DataTable( {
```

...